# Recording how many times a user failed login

Tags: sql, database-normalization

How would you design you database if say you had a table called user:

User_Table : `id, username, password, password_salt, email, email_salt`

Where would you store how many times they have failed login and the last time they failed login?

> total_failed, last_failed_login_time

I also want to record whether their email address is validated or not?

What would be the best way (not necessarily normalized as that involves using a lot of joins) of doing this? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store `total_failed` and `last_failed_login_time` on the `User_Table`.  You can updated it whenever they fail a login.  I think `email_validated` could be stored there too, though I am not sure exactly what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

Both `total_failed` and `last_failed_login_time` are pretty strange fields to store. Typically login failures are used to help detect attacks on a system.

But wouldn't `Total failed` simply creep up over time to the point that it would just be a rough measure of how long and how often a given user has been accessing the system, as a typical user will somtimes mistype their password. So large numbers in this field won't tell much.

`Last_failed_login_time` doesn't seem to confer much either since it wipes out any prior data one might be interested.

Maybe I'm missing the point of tracking this data?

Comment: Presumably, he would wipe out the 'total_failed' column when there was a valid login.

Comment: If your login failed less than x seconds ago from last_failed_login_time you should be made to wait, its to stop bots from trying several login attempts in a second. For example if (now() < last_failed_login_time + 10) { // wait 10 seconds } ... or.. am I talking out of my backside?! Total_failed is within the last 10 mins or so, so as jeff said it would be wiped clean after a successful login

Comment: Things might get tricky though if you wanted to display & warn about failed login attempt(s) once the user has logged in successfully if these fields are reset on a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

You can store both of those fields as part of the user record. The only thing making you non-normalized (to 5NF, anyway; you *are* normalized to 3NF) is the fact that you'd need to make `last_failed_login_time` nullable.

The same is true for `email_validated`. It can be stored as part of the row.

Comment: As a database designer, I wouldn't object much to setting the default value for `last_failed_login_time` to the time the account was created. That way, you wouldn't have to make it nullable.

Comment: @Catcall: That's definitely an option (and having `total_failed = 0` does tell you logically that the account has not failed), but the value, strictly speaking, isn't correct since the user *didn't* fail at that time, but I don't really think it would have much of a practical implication.

Comment: Right. I think it's a small price to pay to get rid of a nullable column.

Answer (score 0):

First, this kind of logging might be better done by the operating system as part of comprehensive security auditing.

From the point of view of database design, there's nothing wrong with storing `total_failed` and `last_failed_login_time` in the user table. But from the network administrator point of view there might be.

Failed logins can be an indicator that you've been targeted for cracking. As a network administrator, I'd rather monitor the number and distribution (number by time of day) of both successful and unsuccessful logins. To do that, they'd have to be stored in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using summary columns for this data, you might want to implement a login attempt table instead.

You could create a table that tracked the user name, the date the login attempt was made, the status of that login attempt (Success, Password Incorrect, Unknown UserName, etc.), and any other pertinent information related to the attempt itself. Including the (attempted) user name would be necessary, since the user ID would be NULL for any attempts using unknown user names.

This structure would allow you to obtain the information you are asking for, as well as other security, auditing, and statistical reporting.